# Trying to have a string reference text from a cell in google App Script - Fangraphs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For strSplitArr: [1,7,228],   I want the "1,7,228" to be pulled from cell B1 where I can change the parameters of B1 cell and the function will pick it up. If I wanted the strSplitArr to be 1,7,228 on on tab but when I enter the formula on another tab, I might want to use "2,9,41,227" instead of 1,7,228 so I just enter that into B1 on the sheet. Not very good at coding by the way...

Thanks for any help

```
function FANGRAPHS(statsType = "season", startDate = "2022-01-01", endDate = "2022-12-31") {
  const payload = {
    strPlayerId: "all",
# strSplitArr: [1,7,228],
    strGroup: statsType,
    strPosition: "B",
    strType: "1",
    strStartDate: startDate,
    strEndDate: endDate,
    strSplitTeams: false,
    dctFilters: [],
    strStatType: "player",
    strAutoPt: "true",
    arrPlayerId: [],
    strSplitArrPitch: [],
```

I've tried replacing the 1,7,228 with a get value lines (var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1');
var value = range.getValue();)

I found them on other sites but clearly copying and pasting into that bracket containing 1,7,228 does not help

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `For strSplitArr: [1,7,228], I want the "1,7,228" to be pulled from cell B1 where I can change the parameters of B1 cell and the function will pick it up. If I wanted the strSplitArr to be 1,7,228 on on tab but when I enter the formula on another tab, I might want to use "2,9,41,227" instead of 1,7,228 so I just enter that into B1 on the sheet.`. In order to correctly understand question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Currently, the input is =FANGRAPHS("career","2021-03-01","2022-11-01") - I would like to add a parameter =FANGRAPHS("career","2021-03-01","2022-11-01","B1") where I enter the split #'s 1,7,288 or 2,9,41 or any other splits that I wish into B1 and it replaces that # in the script on line or strSplitArr: [1,7,228] in the sample script above

The goal is to use the =FANGRAPHS("career","2021-03-01","2022-11-01","B1") on different tabs in the sheet to pull different splits without changing the script every time. Is this slightly more clear? hard to give a practical example but maybe I can try

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Your question must stand on its own. May I respectfully suggest that, as a general statement, users are not familiar with `FANGRAPHS`, its logic, data, relationship to Sheets or Docs, and output, nor the the relevance/purpose/role of `strSplitArr: [1,7,228]` and  the changes that you are trying to make. Please edit your question to explain your function, the changes that you are trying to make, include your entire script, and include an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your question boils down to passing a value in a cell as an array to your Apps Script function. Using `SpreadsheetApp` to do this can be tricky since sometimes the value doesn't get updated on its own. You'll want to do it the regular way by just referencing the cell and writing the data in an array format, then just use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the Apps Script side to turn the string into an array. It should look kind of like this:

```js
function FANGRAPHS(statsType, startDate, endDate, strSplit) {
   const payload = {
    strPlayerId: "all",
    strSplitArr: JSON.parse(`[${strSplit}]`), //just encase it in brackets and parse it
    strGroup: statsType,
    strPosition: "B",
    strType: "1",
    strStartDate: startDate,
    strEndDate: endDate,
    strSplitTeams: false,
    dctFilters: [],
    strStatType: "player",
    strAutoPt: "true",
    arrPlayerId: [],
    strSplitArrPitch: []
    }
   return payload.strSplitArr
  }
```

Then on the Sheet side you can just type the values and reference the cell and you'll see that it gets converted to an array.

[image]